# Stored Proc does not return resultset with JDBC Connection using MS SQL Driver version 4

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, jdbc

For some reason the following stored proc does not return a ResultSet with the MS SQL Driver but it works fine with JTDS.  I tried using prepared statements, callable statements, out parameters, etc.. In all cases I can never get a ResultSet object back.

I'm expecting a VARCHAR of the table name just created/updated. This is SQL 2008 server and the stored proc works fine in the query analyser.

These are some of the ways I called it:

```
"spScheduleSearchCached ?, ?, ?, ?, ?"
"spScheduleSearchCached(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
"{? = call spScheduleSearchCached(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }"
"{ call spScheduleSearchCached(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }"
```

using PreparedStatements and CallableStatements.

I tried with callable to return a result directly by calling statement.getString(1) etc...

Any ideas?  TIA

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE spScheduleSearchCached (
@ProcedureList varchar(1500),
@StartDate smalldatetime,
@ReservationList varchar(1500) = NULL,
@interval int = 60,
@future int = 30,
@PatientID int = NULL )
AS
 DECLARE @tableName varchar(250)
 DECLARE @sqlCreateTable varchar(4096)
 DECLARE @sqlInsertRecords varchar(4096)

 SET @tableName = 'SEARCHRESULT_' + REPLACE (REPLACE (@PROCEDURELIST, ',', '_'), ' ', '') + '_' + convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 112) + '_' + CAST( CAST( RAND() * 99999 as int) as varchar(5))
 SET @sqlCreateTable = N'
    CREATE TABLE ' + @tableName + '
    (
        ID int NOT NULL identity(1, 1)
        , DefaultResult int NULL DEFAULT 0
        , Start1 smalldatetime NULL
        , Room1 int NULL
        , AMPM1 int NULL
    )'

 exec(@sqlCreateTable)

 /* Determine if this is a phased exam */
 IF EXISTS (select 1 from examcode where examcode_no in (select val from fnconverttotable(@ProcedureList)) AND ScheduleWithPhases = 1)
 BEGIN
   -- Phased Exam, make sure there is only one procdure being passed in
   IF (Select count(1) From fnConvertToTable(@ProcedureList)) > 1
    BEGIN
     -- Do Nothing, too many phased procedures passed in
     PRINT 'Only 1 phased procedure at a time'
    END
   ELSE
    BEGIN
     SET @sqlInsertRecords = N'
        INSERT INTO ' + @tableName + '
        (start1, room1, start2, room2, start3, room3, start4, room4, start5, room5)
        EXEC spScheduleSearchPhasedExams ' + @ProcedureList + ', ''' + CONVERT(varchar, @StartDate, 102) + ''', ' + CONVERT(varchar, @interval) + ', ' + CONVERT(varchar, @future) + ', ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, @PatientID), 'NULL')
     EXEC (@sqlInsertRecords)
     SELECT @tableName as resultKey
    END
   END
ELSE
   BEGIN
    SET @sqlInsertRecords = N'
    INSERT INTO ' + @tableName + '
    (start1, room1, start2, room2, start3, room3, start4, room4, start5, room5)
    EXEC spScheduleSearchNormalExams ' + @ProcedureList + ', ''' + CONVERT(varchar, @StartDate, 102) + ''', ' + ISNULL(@ReservationList, 'NULL') + ', ' + CONVERT(varchar, @interval) + ', ' + CONVERT(varchar, @future) + ', ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar, @PatientID), 'NULL')
    EXEC (@sqlInsertRecords)
    SELECT @tableName as resultKey
   END

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
```

Comment: add the code on how you are calling it.

Answer (score 1):

You may be getting back more than one result set?  Try adding the following line:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

JTDS does not need this line but I have add to add this for other drivers.

Comment: I tried it. No difference. Whatever I try I cannot get back the resultset returned by SELECT @tableName as resultKey

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this. The issue is that MSSQL driver returns update count results along with result sets. If your stored proc performs any updates you need to iterate across all result types to find the real resultset.

```
try (CallableStatement st = con.prepareCall(statement)) {
    setParameters(st, params);

    st.execute();
    while (true) {
        boolean queryResult = st.getMoreResults();
        if (queryResult) {
            try (ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet()) {
               // do something here
            }
        } else {
            if (st.getUpdateCount() == -1) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```